# Simplifying PSTricks code

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  landscape,
  margin = 4cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{dimen = m}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(21,8)
  \multido
    {\i = 0+6}
    {4}
    {\psframe(\i,0)(\fpeval{\i+3},2)}
  \multido
    {\i = 3+6}
    {3}
    {\psframe(\i,2)(\fpeval{\i+3},4)
     \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](\i,0)(\fpeval{\i+3},2)
     \rput(\fpeval{\i+1.5},1){\Large $+$}
     \psline{->}(\fpeval{\i-0.2},1.8)(\fpeval{\i+0.2},2.2)
     \psline{->}(\fpeval{\i+3.2},1.8)(\fpeval{\i+2.8},2.2)}
  \multido
    {\i = 6+6}
    {2}
    {\psframe(\i,4)(\fpeval{\i+3},6)
     \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](\i,2)(\fpeval{\i+3},4)
     \rput(\fpeval{\i+1.5},3){\Large $+$}
     \psline{->}(\fpeval{\i-0.2},3.8)(\fpeval{\i+0.2},4.2)
     \psline{->}(\fpeval{\i+3.2},3.8)(\fpeval{\i+2.8},4.2)}
  \multido
    {\i = 9+6}
    {1}
    {\psframe(\i,6)(\fpeval{\i+3},8)
     \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = gray](\i,4)(\fpeval{\i+3},6)
     \rput(\fpeval{\i+1.5},5){\Large $+$}
     \psline{->}(\fpeval{\i-0.2},5.8)(\fpeval{\i+0.2},6.2)
     \psline{->}(\fpeval{\i+3.2},5.8)(\fpeval{\i+2.8},6.2)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I'm sure this can be done much more "elegantly" by using a `\multido` within a `\multido` but I can't get it right. How do I do this?

**Update**

Here is what I ended up with, thanks to user187802's great [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634569/15874):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{dimen = m}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{xfp}

% Parameters
\def\pilStr{0.2}      % arrow size
\def\klodsBredde{2.5} % block width
\def\klodsHoejde{1.6} % block height
\def\pyramideStr{4}   % pyramide size (natural number)

\newcommand*\pil{
  \psline{->}(-\pilStr,-\pilStr)(\pilStr,\pilStr)
}
\def\kasseTom(#1,#2){
  \psframe(#1,#2)
}
\def\kassePlus(#1,#2){
  \psframe[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = gray!75
  ](#1,#2)
  \rput(\fpeval{#1/2},\fpeval{#2/2}){\large$+$}
  \rput(0,#2){\pil}
  \rput{90}(#1,#2){\pil}
}
\newcommand*\pyramideBredde{\fpeval{(2*\pyramideStr-1)*\klodsBredde}}
\newcommand*\pyramideHoejde{\fpeval{\klodsHoejde*\pyramideStr}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pyramide{
  \@ifnextchar(\psPyramide{\psPyramide(2,1)}
}
\def\psPyramide(#1,#2)#3{
    \multido
      {\rX = 0+#1,
       \rY = 0+#2,
       \iZ = 0+1}
      {#3}
      {\multido
         {\rA = \rX+\fpeval{2*#1}}
         {\fpeval{#3-\iZ}}
         {\rput(\rA,\rY){\kasseTom(#1,#2)}}
       \multido
         {\rB = \fpeval{\rX+#1}+\fpeval{2*#1}}
         {\fpeval{#3-\iZ-1}}
         {\rput(\rB,\rY){\kassePlus(#1,#2)}}}
}
\makeatother
\def\udtryk(#1,#2)#3{
  \rput(\fpeval{(2*#1+#2-2.5)*\klodsBredde},\fpeval{(#2-0.5)*\klodsHoejde}){#3}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\pyramideBredde,\pyramideHoejde)
    \pyramide(\klodsBredde,\klodsHoejde){\pyramideStr}
    \udtryk(1,1){$x$}
    \udtryk(2,1){$x$}
    \udtryk(3,1){$y$}
    \udtryk(4,1){$y$}
    \udtryk(1,2){\textcolor{red}{$2x$}}
    \udtryk(2,2){$x + y$}
    \udtryk(3,2){\textcolor{red}{$2y$}}
    \udtryk(1,3){\textcolor{red}{$3x + y$}}
    \udtryk(2,3){\textcolor{red}{$x + 3y$}}
    \udtryk(1,4){\textcolor{red}{$4x + 4y$}}
  \end{pspicture}
  \caption{An addition pyramide.}
  \label{fig:add-pyramide}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: also it's been a while since I used pstricks much but I'm surprised to see fpeval used here, postscript is quite capabable of adding 3.2 without help from a tex floating point package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know that one can add directly using PostScript but I like the syntax provided by `\fpeval`

Comment: yes but you posted working code and just asked for commnts on simplifying it, and a postscript floating point add is zero tex expansions and probably a hardware addition, an fpeval floating point add is hundreds if not thousands of tex expansions and running on an emulated floating point unit implmented in tex integer arithmetic, it seemed worth a comment at least:-)

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the comment. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{dimen = m}
\usepackage{multido}

\def\Arrow{\psline{->}(-0.2,-0.2)(0.2,0.2)}
\def\Frame#1(#2,#3){%
  \psframe#1[linecolor=black!50](#2,#3)%
  \if$#1$\else\rput(!#2 2 div #3 2 div){+}\rput(0,#3){\Arrow}\rput{90}(#2,#3){\Arrow}\fi}
\makeatletter
\def\Bricks{\@ifnextchar(\psBricks{\psBricks(2,1)}}%
\def\psBricks(#1,#2)#3{%
  \begin{pspicture}[calcframe]
  \edef\dX{\numexpr2*#1}%
  \edef\dY{\numexpr2*#2}%
  \multido{\iX=0+#1,\iY=0+#2,\iZ=0+1}{#3}{%
    \multido{\iA=\iX+\dX}{\numexpr#3-\iZ}{\rput(\iA,\iY){\Frame(#1,#2)}}%
    \multido{\iB={\numexpr\iX+#1}+\dX}{\numexpr#3-\iZ-1}{\rput(\iB,\iY){\Frame*(#1,#2)}}%
  }
\end{pspicture}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5}

\Bricks(2,1){4}

\Bricks(3,2){4}

\Bricks{6}

\Bricks(1,1){4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, then it tries to find the box values

Comment: see edited answer. Values must be integers, but code can be adoped to something like `\Bricks(3.12,2.2){4}`

Comment: Then make it right ... where is the problem??

Comment: See edit .........

Comment: define \FrameA nad \FrameB and set it individually instead of \Frame with star or without

Comment: Arrrh! Of course. Thank you very much! (Should we delete all the comments to your answer?)